# rails_admin force format for custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

How can I force the format in a custom action?
For example I have 2 formats, by default rails_admin uses `html` but I want use `pdf` instead:

```
 register_instance_option :controller do
      proc do
        respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render json: @object }
          format.html { render @action.template_name }
          format.pdf {
            render :pdf => "file", :layout => 'rails_admin/pdf.html.haml'
          }
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i tried this and it works fine : 
add this to your custom action  :

```
register_instance_option :default_format do
  'pdf' #your favorite format
end
```

and overwrite rails_admin\application_helper by adding this to menu_for

```
  format: action.try(:default_format)
```

full menu_for method

```
def menu_for(parent, abstract_model = nil, object = nil, only_icon = false ) # perf matters here (no action view trickery)
      actions = actions(parent, abstract_model, object).select { |a| a.http_methods.include?(:get) }
      actions.collect do |action|
        wording = wording_for(:menu, action)
        %(
          <li title="#{wording if only_icon}" rel="#{'tooltip' if only_icon}" class="icon #{action.key}_#{parent}_link #{'active' if current_action?(action)}">
            <a class="#{action.pjax? ? 'pjax' : ''}" href="#{url_for(action: action.action_name, controller: 'rails_admin/main', format: action.try(:default_format) ,model_name: abstract_model.try(:to_param), id: (object.try(:persisted?) && object.try(:id) || nil))}">
              <i class="#{action.link_icon}"></i>
              <span#{only_icon ? " style='display:none'" : ''}>#{wording}</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        )
      end.join.html_safe
end
```